# digital signature pkcs7 encoding getting an error - non-canonical encoding

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle

PKCS#7 not encoding properly. After Decode the data it's showing "non-canonical encoding".

Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    PKCS7Signer signer = new PKCS7Signer();
    KeyStore keyStore = signer.loadKeyStore();
    CMSSignedDataGenerator signatureGenerator = signer.setUpProvider(keyStore);
    String content = "ABCDE1212F";
    byte[] signedBytes = signer.signPkcs7(content.getBytes("UTF-8"), signatureGenerator);
    System.out.println("Signed Encoded Bytes: " + new String(Base64.encode(signedBytes)));

    System.out.println(s.next());
}
```

PKCS7Signer.java

```
public final class PKCS7Signer {
    private static final String PATH_TO_KEYSTORE = "E:\\DSC Work\\keystore.jks";
    private static final String KEY_ALIAS_IN_KEYSTORE = "selfsigned";
    private static final String KEYSTORE_PASSWORD = "password123";
    private static final String SIGNATUREALGO = "SHA256withRSA";

    public PKCS7Signer() {
    }

    KeyStore loadKeyStore() throws Exception {
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_KEYSTORE);
        keystore.load(is, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        return keystore;
    }

    CMSSignedDataGenerator setUpProvider(final KeyStore keystore) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        Certificate[] certchain = (Certificate[]) keystore.getCertificateChain(KEY_ALIAS_IN_KEYSTORE);

        final List<Certificate> certlist = new ArrayList<Certificate>();

        for (int i = 0, length = certchain == null ? 0 : certchain.length; i < length; i++) {
            certlist.add(certchain[i]);
        }

        Store certstore = new JcaCertStore(certlist);

        Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(KEY_ALIAS_IN_KEYSTORE);

        ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(SIGNATUREALGO).setProvider("BC").
                build((PrivateKey) (keystore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS_IN_KEYSTORE, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray())));

        CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

        generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").
                build()).build(signer, (X509Certificate) cert));

        generator.addCertificates(certstore);

        return generator;
    }

    byte[] signPkcs7(final byte[] content, final CMSSignedDataGenerator generator) throws Exception {
        CMSTypedData cmsdata = new CMSProcessableByteArray(content);
        CMSSignedData signeddata = generator.generate(cmsdata, true);
        return signeddata.getEncoded();
    }

}
```

After decoding its showing error like 
[image]

I'm using Bouncy Castle and JDK 1.8. I don't know what is the problem from one week struck in this.

Comment: Your decoder is wrong or inappropriate. Although a small part of a SignedData (or SignedAndEnvelopedData in legacy PKCS7 or AuthenticatedData in CMS) is DER, most of the message is BER and indefinite-length encoding is perfectly fine. And even in the DER part, anyone who knows ASN.1 wouldn't use non-canonical to mean non-DER because 'canonical' normally means CER (where indefinite-length for constructed is _required_). See sec 2 para 3 of rfc5652 et pred